# Flagging duplicate (non-unique) values based on specifications

Tags: r, data.table

`enter code here`I'm working with a dataset, "Final.Export" that looks like this:

```
            LakeID   LakeName SourceVariableName SourceVariableDescription SourceFlags
47    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
48    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
49    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
50    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
51    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
52    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
53    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
54    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
55    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
56    390 Moosehead         Acolor(PCU)            Apparent color        <NA>
   LagosVariableID LagosVariableName Value Units CensorCode DetectionLimit       Date
47              11   Color, apparent    22   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
48              11   Color, apparent    17   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
49              11   Color, apparent    16   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
50              11   Color, apparent    14   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
51              11   Color, apparent    14   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
52              11   Color, apparent    17   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
53              11   Color, apparent    16   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
54              11   Color, apparent    17   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
55              11   Color, apparent    14   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
56              11   Color, apparent    17   PCU         NC             NA 2003-08-26
   LabMethodName LabMethodInfo SampleType SamplePosition SampleDepth MethodInfo
47          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED           6       <NA>
48          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED           7       <NA>
49          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED           6       <NA>
50          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED          10       <NA>
51          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED          10       <NA>
52          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED           9       <NA>
53          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED          10       <NA>
54          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED           8       <NA>
55          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED          10       <NA>
56          <NA>          <NA> INTEGRATED      SPECIFIED          10       <NA>
   BasinType Subprogram Comments Dup
47   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
48   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
49   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
50   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
51   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
52   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
53   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
54   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
55   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
56   UNKNOWN         NA       NA  NA
```

I want to flag all duplicate values as 1. Duplicate values are defined as those that have the exact same values in EVERY column of  'LakeID','Date','LagosVariableID','SampleDepth', and 'SamplePosition' columns.

To do this I have created a new data table "data1" using the following code:

```
library(data.table)
data1=data.table(Final.Export,key=c('LakeID','Date','LagosVariableID','SampleDepth','SamplePosition','Value'))
data1=data1[,Dup:=duplicated(.SD),.SDcols=c('LakeID','Date', 'LagosVariableID', 'SampleDepth', 'SamplePosition','Value')]
data1$Dup[which(data1$Dup==FALSE)]=NA
data1$Dup[which(data1$Dup==TRUE)]=1
```

The problem with "data1" is that only duplicate rows (according to my definition of duplicate) after the first unique row (flagged as NA) are flagged as "1." I need to flag the unique row and the associated duplicate rows as "1." Any ideas how to do this?

If this is confusing let me know how I can clarify.

Comment: It would help to give some sample input and output that reproduces the problem.

Comment: A sample of `Final.Export`, a sample of `Final.Export1` showing the `NA` values that you are trying to avoid, and also show what you want `Final.Export1` to look like.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without a reproducible example, but it seems you want something like this:

```
data1[,dup:=duplicated(.SD), 
       by=list(LakeID, LagosVariableID, Value, Date, SamplePosition, SampleDepth)]
```

**Edit:**

After OP's clarification it appears they simply want this:

```
data1[,dup:=duplicated(.SD), 
 .SDcols=c('LakeID', 'Date', 'LagosVariableID', 'SampleDepth', 'SamplePosition')]
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the OP, but it looks like they want to find duplicates by key, In which case, this can be simplified to `DT[, dup := duplicated(DT)]` (no need for `by`)  -- Also, as of version `1.8.11` `duplicated.data.table` has its own `by` argument